# "You tried to define an association named id on the model x" in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model name id and I got this error: `ArgumentError (You tried to define an association named id on the model User, but this will conflict with a method id already defined by Active Record. Please choose a different association name.)`

Here is the source of the error:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :dob, dependent: :nullify
  has_one :id, class_name: "Id", dependent: :nullify
  ...
end
```

I already try to use class_name but it doesn't work, is there a way to avoit it? or should I change the model name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine the following situation: You open a rails console and type in:

```
User.last.id
```

Now rails does not know, what you want. There are two options:

1. Return the value of the id column of the user table
2. Return the record of the class id with the correct user_id

In short: You can not have both and need to either remove the id from the user model (not recommended) or rename your model. Without knowing, what the model should do: id seems to be a very bad choice as a name. Try something more descriptive.

If you are interested: There is a nice [list of reserved words](https://riptutorial.com/ruby-on-rails/example/32446/reserved-word-list).